# Straight line depreciation confusion

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, finance

My problem:

A computer bought for $3892$ is to be claimed as a tax deduction using straight-line depreciation of 15% of its original value each year until the total value has been claimed. Calculate the number of years that the equal deduction amounts will be claimed.

Textbook answer:

Okay first its said calculate the interest rate which is the 15% of $3892$. Okay this is easy but then this is where i am confused.

It said i need to contruct a formula (Arithmetic Progression) with inequality. (Which i disagree) It then said the deduction will take place until $tn < 0$; the value of the computer becomes less than $0$.

Let $t0 = 3892, t1 = 3892 -584$(interest)$= 3308$ and hence $a = 3308$ and $d = -584$

So the general formula= $tn =3308 - 584(n-1)$

The deduction will take place until$ tn < 0$

it said   $3308 - 584(n-1) < 0$

My question us why? Why not just do $3308 - 584(n-1) = 0$ Where the number of years it takes to deduct the full value of the computer.
***What is the point of inequality in this case?***

Answer (score 1):

You need the inequality because the value may not be exactly $0$ at the end of any year. Suppose the value started at $\$5$ and the depreciation was $\$2$ per year. The formula would be
$$
v = 5 - 2y
$$
which is $0$ when $y=5/2$.